# Select from dynamic table names

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Consider this query.

```
SELECT app_label || '_' || model as name from django_content_type where id = 12;

       name        
-------------------
 merc_benz
```

DJango people might have guessed, 'merc_benz' is a table name in same db. I want to write some SQL migrations and I need to select results from such dynamic table names.

How can i use variable *name* as a table name???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...(see [RETURN QUERY EXECUTE in the plpgsql portion of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html))

```
CREATE function dynamic_table_select(v_id int) returns setof text as $$
DECLARE 
    v_table_name text;
BEGIN
    SELECT app_label || '_' || model into 
    v_table_name from django_content_type where id = v_id;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT a_text_column from '||quote_ident(v_table_name);
    RETURN;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It becomes a little more complex if you want to return more than a single column of one type - either create a TYPE that is representative, or if you're using all the columns of a table, there's already a TYPE of that table name.  You could also specify multiple OUT parameters.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

The basic answer I think is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: Ummm...no, not the link you provided unless he's got his heart set on programming it in C.  Thats embedded SQL in C - you'd have to make, compile, load, etc...